# python subprocess.check_output not able to execute commands like P4

Tags: python

I am able to execute commands in command line but when trying to execute the same command in python using eclipse it throws error like "P4 command does not work on your system. Please ensure that P4 executable is in your path"

I tried executing subprocess.check_output("p4")

Comment: what does it mean "using eclipse"? compare `os.env['PATH']` from script against `$PATH` of terminal that cmd executes without errors

Comment: if I run the same file using python myfile.py in command line , it works. subprocess.check_output("p4") returns proper output. If debugged the same file in eclipse it is throwing error "P4 command does not work on your system"

Comment: compare PATH environments i presume eclipse is mangling it

Comment: thanks . I need to set the path explicitly if working through eclipse. Eclipse somehow not taking the path set in .bash_profiles